# Telnet using JMeter 3.3

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-3.2

I am using Jmeter 3.2 and I need to do a telnet connection and parse the response.

Is it possible using Jmeter 3.2 or adding any plugin?

What I need to achieve is what I would do using this command line

> telnet
>
> open [IP] [PORT]

and understand if the connection is established or not.

Also I wonder what is the effective difference if I simply use a TCP Sampler.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have `groovy` tag here's how you can test the connectivity using [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class, the example code would be something like:

```
def sock = new Socket()
sock.setSoTimeout(1000)
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("example.com",80))

if (sock.isConnected()) {
    log.info('Connection established')
}
else {
    log.info('Server is not listening')
}
```

[image: JMeter Groovy Telnet]

Also be aware that you can invoke `telnet` command directly using String.execute() method like:

```
"telnet example.com 80".execute().text
```

And last but not the least, you can run an arbitrary command or program using JMeter's [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter).